# Easy way to know $\nabla\cdot(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbf{I} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, tensor-products

Given a vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$,

is there some sort of rule to easily catch the fact that
$\nabla\cdot(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbf{I} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T$?

As a beginner, I had to calculate rigorously both sides of the equation using an example
$\mathbf{u}=(u, v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ to finally realize that both sides are actually equivalent.

To elaborate,

LHS: $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbf{I}$:

$\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}j\right)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)\mathbf{I} \\&= \mathbf{\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y}\right)i + \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^2v}{\partial y^2} \right)j}
\end{align}$

RHS: $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T$:

$\begin{align}
&\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}j\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}ii + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}ji + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}ij + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}jj\right)\\&= \left( \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}i +  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}j + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x\partial y}i + \frac{\partial ^2 v}{\partial y^2}j\right) \\&= \mathbf{\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x \partial y}\right)i + \left( \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}\right)j}\end{align}$

So LHS = RHS

Comment: Can you elaborate on your notation? As is, you seem to be taking the divergence of a vector twice, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @CJDowd Yes, I edited the question